# Annotation plugin not working with Chart.js 2.8.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, annotations, chart.js

chartjs version  : 2.8.0

chartjs plugin annotation: 0.5.7

trying to get chart annotation plugin to work on chartjs 2.8.0 - as of now the annotations dont show up at all.

```
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

in chart config:

```
plugins: [ChartAnnotation],
```

in chart options:

```
    annotation: {
  annotations: [
    {
      id: 'a-line-1',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'vertical',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: '25',
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
  ],
},
```

tried encasing the annotation object in a plugin object, to no avail
anyone experienced this issue in the past?

Answer (score 1):

The annotation plugin registers itself in v2, so you just need to import it like so:

```js
import "chartjs-plugin-annotation";
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dust-nqfcz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts